# Do cards that say "all creatures" affect creatures with hexproof?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When a creature or player has hexproof and a player casts a card such as [Cleansing Nova](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCleansing%20Nova%5d):

> Choose one —
>
> - Destroy all creatures.
> - Destroy all artifacts and enchantments.

Do creatures with hexproof die too?

Comment: anytime I use this site I feel attacked.  I talking every time I use it or ask a question there is a problem always.

Comment: hey there, sorry to hear that :/ would you mind clarifying in what way you feel attacked? Is there something we can help you with that hasn't been answered so far?

Comment: @LoneWolf Sorry you feel that way.  As people have told you before, StackExchange is a platform that encourages editing and improving posts to provide a repository of knowledge for current and future users.  Changes that correct spelling/grammatical errors and improve the clarity of your question are the norm on this site.  If this bothers you, then StackExchange may not be the right network for you.

Comment: @LoneWolf If this is about the question being closed as a duplicate, please understand that that action does not in anyway say anything negative about you! Stack Exchange strives to keep duplicates closed so that other visitors looking up the question can find one definitive source for the answer, rather than possibly seeing different answers in different places. Many questions by many users get closed as duplicates here; it doesn't in any way mean that the users are annoyed that you asked the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, cards with "destroy all ..." don't target the permanents they affect, so Hexproof does not protect them from being destroyed.

Generally speaking, if the word 'target' doesn't appear on the card, the spell or ability isn't targeting. Auras are an exception (see rule 114.1b), and sometimes the word 'target' is in the reminder text (e.g. the provoke ability).
<sub>(There might be more exceptions, since Magic: The Gathering is an ever evolving game.)</sub>